Question for TON Developers how to identify swap transactions with python
I am currently building a tool to analyze transactions on the TON blockchain. When I perform a swap transaction (e.g., using a DEX), I typically see 2 or 3 transactions generated in quick succession. I would like to understand how to reliably detect if a set of transactions represents a swap.
Specifically, I have the following questions:
Identifying a Swap: Are there specific patterns, flags, or attributes in the transaction data (such as message data, destinations, or OP codes) that can be used to identify a swap? If so, what should I be looking for?
Token Involvement: How can I determine which tokens are involved in the swap? Is there a way to accurately extract and differentiate the tokens being swapped, including their amounts and destination addresses?
Handling Multiple Transactions: If a swap involves multiple transactions (e.g., an input, a swap operation, and an output), is there a recommended approach to grouping these transactions together to identify them as part of a single swap operation?
Any guidance on these questions, or pointers to relevant documentation or tools, would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to develop a method to detect if a transaction on the TON blockchain is a swap. My approach involved analyzing transaction data retrieved from the TON blockchain API. I looked for patterns in transactions that occur within a short time frame (like 5 minutes) that might indicate a swap, such as specific destination addresses associated with DEX contracts, multiple tokens being sent and received, and specific keywords like 'swap' in the message data. But these didn't work for me. Here is my code
import asyncio
from TonTools import TonCenterClient, Wallet
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Initialize TonCenterClient without an API key
client = TonCenterClient(base_url='https://toncenter.com/api/v2/')

async def check_for_swap(wallet_address):
    # Initialize the Wallet object
    wallet = Wallet(address=wallet_address, provider=client)

    # Fetch transactions for the wallet address
    transactions = await wallet.get_transactions(limit=10)  # Adjust the limit as needed

    # Example DEX contract addresses (replace with actual DEX contract addresses)
    known_dex_contracts = [
        'EQARULUYsmJq1RiZ-YiH-IJLcAZUVkVff-KBPwEmmaQGH6aC',
        'EQA-X_yo3fzzbDbJ_0bzFWKqtRuZFIRa1sJsveZJ1YpViO3r'
    ]

    # Dictionary to track ongoing swaps
    ongoing_swaps = {}

    # Time window to consider transactions as part of the same swap
    swap_time_window = timedelta(minutes=5)

    for tx in transactions:
        tx_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tx.utime)
        tx_time_str = tx_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')

        # Initialize lists to store token transfers
        tokens_received = []
        tokens_sent = []

        # Check if incoming message details are available
        if tx.in_msg:
            source = tx.in_msg.source
            destination = tx.in_msg.destination
            value = tx.in_msg.value
            msg_data = tx.in_msg.msg_data

            # Check if the transaction is related to a known DEX contract
            is_dex_tx = source in known_dex_contracts or destination in known_dex_contracts

            # Create a unique key based on the swap's DEX and timestamp
            swap_key = f"{destination}-{tx_time_str}" if source == wallet_address else f"{source}-{tx_time_str}"

            # Determine if this transaction is part of an ongoing swap or a new one
            if swap_key in ongoing_swaps:
                ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_sent'].extend(tokens_sent)
                ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_received'].extend(tokens_received)
            else:
                # Start a new swap
                ongoing_swaps[swap_key] = {
                    'timestamp': tx_time,
                    'tokens_sent': tokens_sent,
                    'tokens_received': tokens_received
                }

            # Check if it's an outgoing transaction from the user's wallet to a DEX
            if source == wallet_address and destination in known_dex_contracts:
                # Add the outgoing token transfer to the current swap
                ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_sent'].append((destination, value))

            # Check if it's an incoming transaction from a DEX to the user's wallet
            elif destination == wallet_address and source in known_dex_contracts:
                # Add the incoming token transfer to the current swap
                ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_received'].append((source, value))

            # Check outgoing messages for token transfers
            for out_msg in tx.out_msgs:
                if out_msg.destination and out_msg.value:
                    if out_msg.destination in known_dex_contracts:
                        ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_sent'].append((out_msg.destination, out_msg.value))
                    else:
                        ongoing_swaps[swap_key]['tokens_received'].append((out_msg.destination, out_msg.value))

        else:
            print("Transaction does not have incoming messages to check.")

    # After processing all transactions, print consolidated swap information
    for swap_id, swap_info in ongoing_swaps.items():
        print(f"\nSwap detected involving DEX at {swap_info['timestamp'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')}")
        print("Tokens Sent:")
        for token in swap_info['tokens_sent']:
            print(f"  - Token: {token[0]}, Amount: {token[1]}")
        print("Tokens Received:")
        for token in swap_info['tokens_received']:
            print(f"  - Token: {token[0]}, Amount: {token[1]}")

async def main():
    # Replace with the wallet address you want to track
    wallet_address = 'Tonwalletaddress'

    # Check for swap transactions for the wallet address
    await check_for_swap(wallet_address)

# Run the async main function
asyncio.run(main())



What DEX do you use? Have you checked the op codes of the 3 txs you've mentioned? If yes, what are they?
